# Django Unit Test for testing a file download

Tags: django, unit-testing

Right now I'm just checking the response of the link like so:

```
self.client = Client()
response = self.client.get(url)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Is there a Django-ic way to test a link to see if a file download event actually takes place? Can't seem to find much resource on this topic.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If the url is meant to produce a file rather than a "normal" http response, then its `content-type` and/or `content-disposition` will be different.

the response object is basically a dictionary, so you could so something like

```
self.assertEquals(
    response.get('Content-Disposition'),
    "attachment; filename=mypic.jpg"
)
```

more info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

UPD:
If you want to read the actual contents of the attached file, you can use response.content. Example for a zip file:

```
try:
    f = io.BytesIO(response.content)
    zipped_file = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r')

    self.assertIsNone(zipped_file.testzip())        
    self.assertIn('my_file.txt', zipped_file.namelist())
finally:
    zipped_file.close()
    f.close()
```

Comment: do you mean you want to check on the actual contents of the file?  you can use `response.content` -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#id4

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact thing but getting the error "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" whenever I do anything with response.content, even passing it to StringIO.

Comment: Looks like this is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359451/django-test-file-download-valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file/20052899#20052899

Comment: Ran into the same issue as @JustinBlake but the solution linked is not ideal.

The IO error is a fault of Django's test client closing the response: https://git.io/vidaR

Using a streaming response bypasses the issue, only because the test client does not close the response but I would not recommend changing production code. Note this warning from the docs:

> StreamingHttpResponse should only be used in situations where it is absolutely required ... for example the ETag and Content- Length headers can’t be generated

Comment: Works for me using `io.BytesIO` (Python 3) instead of StringIO.StringIO (this is for Python 2, in Python 3 we call StringIO after `io` module, io.StringIO gives error: `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`). So I did `f = io.BytesIO(response.content)` and it worked.

Comment: For an `HttpStreamingResponse` use `io.BytesIO(b"".join(response.streaming_content))`.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are returning is a [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects), then you need to know that it returns a [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse). If so, there's no `content` on this type of response.

```
{AttributeError}AttributeError('This FileResponse instance has no `content` attribute. Use `streaming_content` instead.')
```

You need to first evaluate the entire streaming_content, and then read from the buffer.

```
import io

with io.BytesIO(b"".join(response.streaming_content)) as buf_bytes:
    loaded_response_content = buf_bytes.read()
```