# django test file download - "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have code for a view which serves a file download, and it works fine in the browser. Now I am trying to write a test for it, using the internal django Client.get:

```
    response = self.client.get("/compile-book/", {'id': book.id})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEquals(response.get('Content-Disposition'), 
                      "attachment; filename=book.zip")
```

so far so good. Now I would like to test if the downloaded file is the one I expect it to download. So I start by saying:

```
    f = cStringIO.StringIO(response.content)
```

Now my test runner responds with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../tests.py", line 154, in test_download
    f = cStringIO.StringIO(response.content)
  File "/home/epub/projects/epub-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 282, in content
    self._consume_content()
  File "/home/epub/projects/epub-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 278, in _consume_content
    self.content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(e) for e in self._container)   
  File "/home/epub/projects/epub-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 278, in <genexpr>
    self.content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(e) for e in self._container)   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in next 
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize) 
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Even when I do simply: self.assertIsNotNone(response.content) I get the same ValueError

The *only* topic on the entire internet (including django docs) I could find about testing downloads was this stackoverflow topic: [Django Unit Test for testing a file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244220/django-unit-test-for-testing-a-file-download). Trying that solution led to these results. It is old and rare enough for me to open a new question.

Anybody knows how the testing of downloads is supposed to be handled in Django? (btw, running django 1.5 on python 2.7)

Comment: Have you found an solution to this issue?  I am having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 6):

This works for us. We return `rest_framework.response.Response` but it should work with regular Django responses, as well.

```
import io
response = self.client.get(download_url, {'id': archive_id})
downloaded_file = io.BytesIO(b"".join(response.streaming_content))
```

Note:
`streaming_content` is only available for `StreamingHttpResponse` (also Django 1.10):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse.streaming_content

Answer (score 1):

I had some file download code and a corresponding test that worked with Django 1.4. The test failed when I upgraded to Django 1.5 (with the same `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` error that you encountered).

I fixed it by changing my non-test code to use a `StreamingHttpResponse` instead of a standard `HttpResponse`. My test code used `response.content` so I first migrated to `CompatibleStreamingHttpResponse`, then changed my test code code to use `response.streaming_content` instead to allow me to drop `CompatibleStreamingHttpResponse` in favour of `StreamingHttpResponse`.