# AssertionError: None != 'attachment; filename=filename.extension'

Tags: unit-testing, csv, download, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get the filename of a file that is being downloaded while testing. I've took a reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244220/django-unit-test-for-testing-a-file-download) but couldnot get the solution. I'm quite a noob in testing. Can anyone help me get the name of the filename that is being downloaded in unit testing? Thanks in advance

test.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, force_authenticate
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from csv_loader.api.views import UserViewSet


class UserTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'testuser1'
        self.email = 'testuser1@gmail.com'
        self.password = '!superuser'
        self.superuser = User.objects.create_user(username='superuser', email='uid.sawyer@gmail.com',
                                                  password='superuser',
                                                  is_staff=True)
        self.token = Token.objects.get(user=self.superuser)


    def test_superuser_file_download(self):
        user = User.objects.get(username='superuser')
        view = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
        request = self.factory.get('/api/users/user_download/')
        force_authenticate(request, user, token=self.token)
        response = view(request)
        self.assertEquals(
            response.get('Content-Disposition'),
            "attachment; filename=users.csv"
        )
        )
```

Views.py

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdmin, ]

    @action(detail=False, methods=["get"], permission_classes=[IsAdmin, ])
    def user_download(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['username', 'email'])

        for user in users:
            writer.writerow([user.username, user.email])

        return response
```

serializers.py

```
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FileUpload
        fields = ('created', 'datafile')
```

Error

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_superuser_file_download (csv_loader.tests.tests.UserTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Desktop/CSV/Tasks/Docker/csv-loader/csv_loader/tests/tests.py", line 245, in test_superuser_file_download
    "attachment; filename=users.csv"
AssertionError: None != 'attachment; filename=users.csv'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.208s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the `Content-Disposition` you need to access the response `headers` - you can do that through `request.META.get('HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION')`, for example.